# If 'text' is not included in active div - operator

Tags: javascript, jquery, operators

I have a function, which creates a div on click. This should just happen, if the div with the same text is not already existing. I tried several things.

```
if (div.text().indexOf(type) == 0)
if (div.innerHTML.indexOf(type) == 0)
if (!div.hasOwnProperty(type))
```

embedded in this function

```
a.click(function(json) {
  var type = $(this).data("type");
  saveType();

  function saveType(root) {
    if (typeof root === 'undefined') {
      root = $('#category_wrapper');
    }
    var div = $("<div id='typeSaved' class='waves-effect waves-light btn '>" + type + "</div>");
    if (!div.hasOwnProperty(type)) {
      root.append(div);
    }
  }
})
```

Does somebody know, how to write the if statement correctly?

Comment: add something to the div to identify it by. like a data-text attribute and then compare it

Comment: Why do you define a local function with an argument, but then not pass an argument to it?

Comment: You seem to do that frequently, judging by your previous questions.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I just started to learn JS. Do you have a reference to learn some better practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test for specific div content in string test like this:

```
$('div:contains('+test+')').filter(function(){ return $(this).text() == test; }).length > 0
```

The :contains match is just a substring test, but after we've filtered it that far. The .filter() operation will then test this set of elements for an exact match.

Comment: Great. I adjusted it a little bit and now it works for me.   `if ($('div:contains(' + type + ')').filter(function () { return $(this).text() == type; }).length == 0)`. 
Thank you.